# Kerberos login context gets reset for TableMapReduceUtil while using Ooize

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, kerberos, oozie

I try to run a mapreduce job on a Kerberos protected CDH cluster..The job reads a file from hdfs(mapper) and writes to the hbase table (reducer/TableMapReduceUtil) class.

The job configuration that I made is ,

```
Configuration hbaseConfigurarion =  HBaseConfiguration.create();            
hbaseConfigurarion.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", args[1]);
hbaseConfigurarion.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
hbaseConfigurarion.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
hbaseConfigurarion.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml"));
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
hbaseConfigurarion.addResource(new Path("/etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml"));

Job job = new Job(hbaseConfigurarion, "hdfs_hbase_test");
job.setJarByClass(HdfsHbaseTestDriver.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(args[2], null , job);
```

This mapreduce job executes well when I run it using 'hadoop jar ' command, It automatically does the kerberos authentication with the TGT tickets stored in the cache which are valid and renewed.Consider here the user name principal is MY_ID@COMPANY.COM.

But When I run this job with oozie workflow , it gets failed with the following exception from the line TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob().

```
2014-09-25 20:19:21,611 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:MY_ID (auth:SIMPLE) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

2014-09-25 20:19:21,612 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2014-09-25 20:19:21,613 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClient.java:762)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.access$600(RpcClient.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection$2.run(RpcClient.java:883)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection$2.run(RpcClient.java:880)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClient.java:880)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.getConnection(RpcClient.java:1535)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1424)
.
.
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
```

Really I am not sure how come the logged-in user name MY_ID@COMPANY.COM becomes just MY_ID and the KERBEROS auth method becomes SIMPLE while TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob() line is executed when running with oozie workflow..

Is there anymore configuration that I am missing....Kindly suggest....

Answer (score 0):

add TableMapReduceUtil.initCredentials(job);